# How to setup cookie domain?

Tags: 8, cookies

I am trying to set `$cookie_domain` in my settings.php within Drupal 8.

In Drupal 7, I add this in settings.php to set it up, but I am not sure how to do it in Drupal 8:

> $cookie_domain = ".domain.com";

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a container parameter now.

Put this in services.yml or another service definition YAML file:

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_domain: '.domain.com'
```

Since it is in a yaml file, it can't easily be dynamic, one option you have is having multiple yml files, and you dynamically add the one for the right environment, or you have a services.local.yml, just like settings.local.php that you have on each environment and not in git.

Comment: You are right. I'm just adding that any additional YAML file can be loaded in the settings or local.settings files like this :

`$settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/ENV.services.yml';`

Comment: Is it possible to set `IP Address`, Instead of domain?

Comment: @AshwinP There should be hostname what the browsers will see, so if your users access site by IP address it will work like this. But usually users use domain name. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option for multiple environments rather than keeping multiple files is to use environment variables.

[Create an environment variable](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/) the way you normally would, if you're using Docker that would usually be by [loading an `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) with contents such as:

```
COOKIE_DOMAIN=.domain.com
```

Then use that environment variable in your services.yml file (or other YAML file) like this:

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_domain: ${COOKIE_DOMAIN}
```

Comment: This is really neat, didn't know you could use environment variables in container yamls.

Comment: I don't know if env variable approach worked in the past, but at the moment it's not supported. I think there is an issue on d.o to introduce a similar approach to how symfony allows is using the `%env(COOKIE_DOMAIN)` construct.
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2879846

Comment: Setting a `COOKIE_DOMAIN` env var and expecting it to work by itself will not work no. You need to insert it into the services.yml file as shown in the answer. You could use any name for the env var that you like.