# Multi-domain cookie

Tags: cookies, 8

The website I'm working on has 5 domains (two top level and 3 subs, not including www). I need to limit the cookie that the site creates to only work on 4 of the domains.

I have found [from here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233750/how-to-setup-cookie-domain-in-drupal-8/233753#233753) that in Drupal 8 cookies are defined in the services.yml file using this:

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_domain: '.domain.com'
```

But I'm unsure how I can add multiple domains. Is it as simple as something like this?

```
cookie_domain: 'www.domain1.com'; 'domain1.com'; 'sub1.domain.com'; 'sub2.domain.com'
```

Answer (score 4):

A cookie can only have 1 domain value. So you can either set it to a specific domain or the top domain wich includes all the subdomains.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question and your answer is contradictory. If I set it to the top level domain then more than 1 domain can be used i.e a global cookie. How do I limit it to only specific sub domains?

Comment: Further more, drupal handles assigning cookies for both my top level domains without this setting, how would I replicate this if I were to use the cookie_domain value so cookies won't work on sub domains?

Comment: The answer seems clear, to me: Or you set `cookie_domain` to .example.com, which means _all the sub-domains of example.com_ (including example.com), or you set it to sub.example.com, or example.com, which makes the cookie just for a domain.

Comment: I know how cookies work but this isn't a cookie issue it's a dynamic drupal issue. Multi domain cookies could be used in earlier versions of drupal https://www.drupal.org/node/1348784 how do I do this in Drupal 8???

Comment: Without having the cookie_domain set, both of my top level domains handle logins fine, how would I replicate this setting? If I can only input one domain then the other will stop working. Also I apologies if I'm appearing blunt, I do appreciate any help :)

Comment: OK, I've done a little more research and it looks like the only way to achieve this is by using a dynamically loaded services.yml file, loaded based on the current domain and each containing the right cookie_domain value. Any idea which file defines where the settings.yml file is located?

Comment: @Krypton – You ever managed to get this working? Dynamically? If yes, I'd be happy you could drop an answer to your question. :)