# Cookie sharing on multidomain site

Tags: 8, domain-access, cookies

Can somebody please clarify, that cookie sharing in Drupal 8 is just possible for sub domains siblings of the same parent domain.

Before this was discussed here:
[Multi-domain cookie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237220/multi-domain-cookie/287244#287244) - unfortunately just in a sub domain context.

To use the administration session of domain1.com on domain2.com is NOT possible due to security reasons (browser specific).

Or in other words: To be able to use the drupal8 administration area of content that is separated into 3 top level domains via the the "domain module" you must login 3 times.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. (filling minimum character limit)

Comment: The domain must be the same. You can share cookies between subdomains, but not different domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really a Drupal question, but a browser question.

The cookies a browser has for example.com will never be sent to example.org.

You can look at other ways to create federated login, but they are not simple.

To log in and administer 3 separate top level domains you either must log in 3 separate times or use some other form of federated login.

Comment: Re: federated login, OP should look at https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth